# Intergrating of AirtelMoney API to Android App

Tags: android, mpesa, airtelmoney

Well we can count more than three years since [Safaricom](https://safaricom.com/) released the M-Pesa APIs as RESTful APIs accessible through their [developer portal](https://developer.safaricom.co.ke/). Their [Github repository](https://github.com/safaricom), has a sample android application that uses "[Lipa na M-Pesa Online](https://developer.safaricom.co.ke/docs#lipa-na-m-pesa-online-payment)" API. This API initiates an M-Pesa transaction on behalf of the user of an app, the user needs only to input their M-Pesa PIN to complete the transaction.

```
public STKPushService mpesaService() {
    return getRestAdapter().create(STKPushService.class);
}
```

Now is their something similar for AirtelMoney because I have clients who want to have all the mobile money payments we have in Kenya in their app. Its worrying that their is more of Mpesa than other apis? I am looking for a way to incorporate airtel money to my app like we do on Mpesa because we already have apps that support airtel money

> POST https://sandbox.safaricom.co.ke/mpesa/stkpush/v1/processrequest

Has anyone tried this [AirtelMoneyLib](https://github.com/drizzentic/AirtelMoneyLib) which I see was last updated 3 years ago.

```
<?php
/**
 *
 */
require_once('config/Constant.php');
require_once('lib/AirtelMoney.php');
$airtelclient=new AirtelMoney;
//Call the processing function with parameters as shown
//You can do a retrieval of data from a request at this point
//Not advisable to pass the username and password in request. Rather use an environment variable for the same
/**
 * $Username=$_POST['username'];
 * $password=$_POST['password'];
 * $msisdn=$_POST['msisdn'];
 * $referenceId=$_POST['referenceId'];
 * $timeFrom=$_POST['timeFrom'];
 * $timeTo=$_POST['timeTo'];
 */
$referenceId="1601056579194";
$timeTo="";
$timeFrom="";
$airtelclient->processMerchantQuery(USERNAME,PASSWORD,$referenceId,MSISDN,REQUEST1,$timeTo,$timeFrom);
?>
```

I need to know a few things that are making it hard for me to even get some feedback when a `http request` is sent. 
A recent google search pulled up new API called [LIPISHA](http://developer.lipisha.com) now kind off open source on [github](https://github.com/lipisha) how the set back with it is that it comes with a [huge price tag](https://lipisha.com/payments/accounts/index.php/app/launch/pricing) 
That is why am trying to see how this old api can work for me

Answer (score 1):

There is a new SDK library currently in beta testing that I have been working on under a company called Interswitch. It will handle multiple payment channels including cards banks and multiple mobile money providers. Currently it handles Visa, Mastercard, Verve, Mpesa and Equitel. Soon more will be added. I don't know about pricing at the moment but you can reach out to Interswitch for a test account and I'll be able to provide technical support that you may need in integrating. Check out the code at [its github repo](https://github.com/interswitch-kenya-limited/mobpay)